# Three.js JSONLoader 'onLoad is not a function'

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm trying to set up a very simple scene with Three.js, showing an imported mesh rotating. I combined a couple of the examples from the Three.js documentation and arrived at the following code:

```
var scene, camera, renderer;
var geometry, material, mesh;

init();
animate();

function init(){
    scene = new THREE.Scene();

    camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000);
    camera.position.z = 1000;

    // geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(200, 200, 200);
    var jsonLoader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
    jsonLoader.load('handgun.js', object_to_scene(geometry, material));
}

function object_to_scene(geometry, material){
    material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
        color: 0xff0000,
        wireframe: true
    });

    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(mesh);

    renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
}

function animate(){
    requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    mesh.rotation.x += 0.01;
    mesh.rotation.y += 0.02;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

You can see the original example commented out in the above, where we generated a Box using Three.js. That worked fine. However, importing the JSON file of the custom 3D model isn't working. Checking my console reveals the following error:

```
TypeError: onLoad is not a function                three.js:18294:4
    THREE.JSONLoader.prototype.load/<()            three.js:18294
    THREE.XHRLoader.prototype.load/<()             three.js:18010
```

This appears to be an error with Three.js itself, however I've found only two instances of people reporting it on the Github account, and both were told that the Github was for reporting bugs, not asking for help (if this isn't a bug, then what is it?).

Has anyone else encountered this issue, and if you have resolved it, how did you do so?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
jsonLoader.load( 'handgun.js', object_to_scene( geometry, material ) );
```

You need to do this:

```
jsonLoader.load( 'handgun.js', object_to_scene );
```

`object_to_scene( geometry, material )` is a function call that, in your case, returns `undefined`.

three.js r.75

Comment: Thank you! I'm not sure how that error cascaded down into Three.js giving me the TypeError I ultimately encountered, but it does seem to have fixed it (with a couple other changes to the code).

Comment: Then I suggest you take the time to understand it. I gave you an explanation as to why.

Comment: Completely unnecessarily snarky comments aside, no you didn't. You gave me a solution - which I appreciate - but I don't immediately see an obvious explanation as to why an undefined function HERE would cause a pre-existing function inside Three.js to be undefined, nor is it obvious to me why passing parameters in the function causes it to be undefined. But, to be clear, I'm not, nor was I, asking for you to explain it to me. I know that's not the point of SO.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not mean that sentence to sound that way. You are correct, it can be interpreted as being very rude. My apologies. I should have written, "I think it would be a good idea if you to take the time to understand the error"... The reason for the error is the 2nd argument expects a pointer to a function. You _called_ the function, instead, passing in your global variables `geometry`, and `position` into it. It is a Javascript issue; not a three.js issue.

Comment: I also apologize for my strong reaction - I've come to expect snarkiness from SO at this point. Thank you for clarifying, and for your explanation, it makes perfect sense now!